# Why does an increase in reduced mass lead to a decrease in frequency?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In terms of IR spectrum, why does an increase in reduced mass lead to a decrease in frequency?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Finally, we have an important policy: your questions (especially [homework questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/189)), should show your own work or thinking that you have already done in an initial attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a simple molecule $\ce{A-B}$ composed of atoms $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ and let the bond connecting them be described as a spring.  Then the stretching and contracting of the $\ce{A-B}$ bond (spring) can be considered as a simple harmonic oscillation and is described by [Hooke's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law).

${\nu = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}}$

where ${\nu}$ is the frequency of the stretch,  ${k}$ is the force constant describing the specific spring and ${m}$ is the mass of the system.  In our $\ce{A-B}$ example, the mass of the system is described by the reduced mass ${\mu}$, where

${\mu = \frac{m_A m_B}{m_A + m_B}}$

So our equation becomes

${\nu = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sqrt{\frac{k}{\mu}}}$

From this equation we can see that as the reduced mass increase's the stretching frequency will become smaller.

Comment: that's not hooke's law, it is a consequence of it used to describe by SHM